# How to seperate asset folders by locale?

Tags: assets, localization

I have a website where the client can add links to assets (pdf, doc, etc.) anywhere on a page. So I would like to avoid having a assetField on every template. I would like them to upload all assets in the CP on the assets page and than link to them from a page. That's doable.

But, I have one page where I need to list all assets from a certain source. Also doable. But that source has 3 subfolders, one for every locale. However, when files are uploaded in the CP on the assets page, they automatically have properties for all locales.

I only want to fetch the files for a given locale (so a given subfolder). I can do that by using folderId.
But if a file doesn't exist in one locale, I'd like to default to the same file in another locale. That is the issue I can't get right. How would I proceed? There is no real link between different files which are essentialy the same files but in different languages.